# how to create a dependent drop-down lists in pyqt

Tags: python, user-interface, pyqt4

I want to create two dependent drop-down lists in pyqt4, here is my syntaxe there is no error, but it doesn't work.

```
liste1=["value1","value2"]
self.comboBox.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(128, 30, 140, 22))
self.comboBox.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("comboBox"))
self.comboBox.addItems(liste1)
self.comboBox_2 = QtGui.QComboBox(self.groupBox_6)
self.comboBox_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(180, 40, 69, 22))
self.comboBox_2.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("comboBox_2"))
if self.comboBox.currentText()=="value1":
            liste_b=['1','2','3','4','5','6','7']
            self.comboBox_2.addItems(liste_b)
 if self.comboBox.currentText()=="value2":
            liste_b=['1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10','11','12']
            self.comboBox_2.addItems(liste_b)
```

Comment: I assume what you mean by dependent is that the values of comboBox_2 will change depending on the values of comboBox. If that is the case, the only way I know to achieve this is to connect the ".currentIndexChanged" signal of comboBox to a method that updates the items in comboBox_2.

Comment: Thank you. i've tried it and it works.